# Can I install "Caffe , Deep Learning" without a Nvida GPU

Tags: ubuntu, caffe, amd-gpu

I want to install Caffe on my laptop with AMD GPU ON Ubuntu 16 and all installations I find are installations with NVIDIA dependencies!
I have tried to install the NVIDIA driver but I end up with losing my Ubuntu OS.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: Is your laptop's CPU up to the task?  If so, then you could make the switch to CPU and install Caffe that way.  If the CPU is there mainly to drive the GPU facilities, then I don't know whether there's a solution.

Answer (score 2):

From the official [Caffe installation documentation](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html) :

> CPU-only Caffe: for cold-brewed CPU-only Caffe uncomment the CPU_ONLY
>   := 1 flag in Makefile.config to configure and build Caffe without
>   CUDA. This is helpful for cloud or cluster deployment.

This will allow you to compile Caffe without any GPU dependency.

Alternatively, there is an experimental [Open-CL Caffe fork](https://github.com/amd/OpenCL-caffe) developed by AMD.